# Qr_code from Ruby on Rails app to Telegram bot

Tags: ruby, telegram, qrcode, bot

estoy tratando de enviar un codigo QR generado en mi app RoR, que se genera y guarda correctamente en la misma app, a mi bot de telegram. Pese a que hago eso con mensajes dentro de la app, no he podido lograr recibir el QR. Cambié el metodo de photo a QR image pero nada. Es posible que alguien lo haya hecho y logrado con éxito?

```
    require 'mini_magick'

class QrCode < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :route

  after_create :generate_qr_data

  private

  def generate_qr_data
    qr_url = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.route_url(route, host: 'franck-claudia-c4yg.onrender.com')
  
    begin
      qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new(qr_url)
      svg_data = qr.as_svg(
        offset: 0,
        color: '000',
        shape_rendering: 'crispEdges',
        module_size: 3,
        standalone: true
      )
  
      self.update(data: svg_data)
  
      png_file_path = save_svg_and_convert_to_png(svg_data)
  
      send_qr_to_telegram(png_file_path) if png_file_path
    rescue StandardError => e
      Rails.logger.error "Error generating or sending QRCode: #{e.message}"
    end
  end

  ...

  def send_qr_to_telegram(file_name)

    qr_file_path = Rails.root.join('public', 'qrcodes', file_name)
  
    TelegramService.new.send_qr_code(qr_file_path, 'png')
  rescue StandardError => e
    Rails.logger.error "Error sending QR to Telegram: #{e.message}"
  end
end
```

The API call is okay because I'm receiving the other messages. The app is running but if I try to send the QR image I have trouble.